# Is there a way to disable relative dates and times on posts and comments?

Tags: support, user-interface

I often see *fuzzy* and relative times given for things around the site like "edited 1 hour ago".

This isn't a problem when you first load the screen but after a while, unless you refresh, those relative times don't [always*] update. And what if I saved the page locally or printed it? Those relative times lose all meaning. In those cases it would be better if the full date-time was displayed.

Is there any way to disable relative times on the entire site?

<sub>*From Oli: I've both seen some times update and some *not* update. I've no idea what the actual functionality does or where it does it. I might even be hallucinating.</sub>

Comment: @user227096 Why not ask for a userscript over on stackapps?

Comment: If you leave the pointer over the time for 1-2 seconds it will appear the exact time.

Comment: It would seem that the answer is:<br/><br/>NO

Comment: The answer is you're asking the wrong question.  The absolute time in Zulu time is readily available in the span element of class="relativetime" as the title element.  It would be simple to implement if someone were to ask nicely and in the right place.

Comment: I created a user script to replace them http://stackapps.com/questions/4450/replace-all-relative-times-with-local-times

Comment: @Dan - awesomesauce.  Now to tweak it to not require a hover and the OP's Christmas wish is fulfilled...

Comment: @hbdgaf just replace .on by .each, but I prefer the hover myself to keep both types of dates always available

Answer (score 1):

I have created a user-script and added a post for it on stackapps [Replace all relative times with local times](https://stackapps.com/questions/4450/replace-all-relative-times-with-local-times)

For info on how to install user-scripts in different browsers, check the info of the [script](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) tag in stackapps .

The script will replace the relative dates with your local date after hovering over a date. I made it like that, because sometimes the relative date is more useful. Specially when it's `x minutes ago` or `x hours ago`.

---

If you know what you are doing already and don't need any of the above info:

> To view the source of the script:
>   https://gist.github.com/dannyhajj/8057530
>
> To install the script click [here](https://gist.github.com/dannyhajj/8057530/raw/showlocaltime.user.js).